# How to run a query asynchronously from MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, events, mysql-workbench

Say you have a query you want to run on your database, but you know that query is going to take a long time to complete, and you don't have direct access to the machine where MySQL is running, or to some other endpoint which has a stable connection with that machine. What do you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you create a one time event that performs the necessary query.

Something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT <event_name>
ON SCHEDULE 
AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 10 SECOND
ENABLE DO 
BEGIN
    -- log the event started
    INSERT INTO EventLogs (`Name`, `Start`, `Query`)
    VALUES (<event_name>, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, <query_string>);
    -- run the query
    ....
    ...    <query>
    ....
    -- log the event done
    UPDATE EventLogs 
    SET `Done` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    WHERE `Name` = <event_name>;
END
```

The above template can handle any arbitrary query.